# Print a complete line if the regex pattern in fluentd is not matching

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I have a requirement to print a part of a message that matches a specific pattern. In some cases the message doesnt have that pattern; in that case i need to display the whole line. For eg the value in MESSAGE field can be any of the two:

Case 1 :`2021-03-31 12:12:05.856 LOG     : Message <checked [abc]>`

Case 2: `No Message was found`

The fluentd filter is:

```
<filter docker>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true  
  <record>
   MESSAGE ${record["MESSAGE"].scan(/:\ (.*+)$/).first} 
  </record>  
</filter>
```

The filter works fine for case 1. and it prints `Message <checked [abc]>` but returns empty for case 2 wherein i need it to print `No Message was found`. How can i print the message even when condition is not satisfied.
Thanks

Comment: Try: `MESSAGE ${ v = record['MESSAGE'].scan(/:\ (.*+)$/).first; !(v.nil? || v.empty?) ? v : 'No message was found' }`

Comment: Can we replace 'No message was found' with a regex so that there is no dependence on the string

Comment: Another alternative, assuming that the first part will be `nil` in case of no match: `MESSAGE ${ record['MESSAGE'].scan(/:\ (.*+)$/).first || 'No message was found' }`. I'm not sure about the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
MESSAGE ${record["MESSAGE"].scan(/^.+: (.+)$|^(.*)$/).first.compact}
```

**Edit**:

The last part of the regexp (in your case, the second half) will capture the line when the previous parts don't match. It's a common technique in regexps; some people may call it "garbage collection"?

As I introduced a second capture group, you'll get an array containing two groups. If a group didn't capture anything then its value will be `nil`. That's why you can call `compact` to get rid of the `nil` captures; that  will reduce the array to only one element.

```
regexp = /^.+: (.+)$|^(.*)$/

'2021-03-31 12:12:05.856 LOG     : Message <checked [abc]>'.scan(regexp).first.compact
# => ["Message <checked [abc]>"]

'No Message was found'.scan(regexp).first.compact
# => ["No Message was found"]
```

Comment: But this results in the full line 2021-03-31 12:12:05.856 LOG : Message <checked [abc]>
But in this case i need  only the part after colon i.e Message <checked [abc]> and in the other case where there is no colon it should print the whole line

Comment: Did you try it ? It should do what you want

Comment: Sorry I have one another issue regarding regex in fluentd. I need to match another pattern, for eg: 2021-03-31 12:12:05.856 LOG  [Test] a.b.c.c.myclass    : Message <checked [abc]>  I need to extract a.b.c.c.myclass I tried with the regex      ([a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)\ +:         But this results in 2 match groups :1. a.b.c.c.myclass
2. .myclass  How can i have exactly one match as when i try scan(/([a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)\ +:/).first it still lists both matches seperated by comma, wherein i want only the first one

Comment: Just use a non capturing group: `([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)\ +:`

Comment: I have one more query as it is relatted to the same config i am not sure if i need to ask as a new question. Is it possible to specify datatype for a field in the filter, for e.g. <record>
   LOGGINGTIME ${record["MESSAGE"].scan(/\d+-\d+-\d+\ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+/).last}
  </record>
i am not able to sort this field in Elastic search as it shows 'unknown field' can i assign date type to this to record.

Comment: I don't know ElasticSearch so I have no idea how to add a datatype in it. You should ask a new question about it.

Comment: ITs regarding adding datatype to fluentd record

Comment: Well, I don't know it either, sorry. Fluentd and ElasticSearch are "products" that I have never played with.

Answer (score 0):

I need to create a new field 'status' if the log field contains a specific string. I tried below code in fluentd but this doesnt work. I need to check if the log field contains the string 'error:' then the new field status should have error else if it has ok it should have ok.

```
<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true  
  <record>
   status ${record["log"].scan(/^.* ([[:<:]]error[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]ok[[:>:]]):.*$/i).first.compact} 
  </record>  
</filter>
```

The error I get is error = undefined method `compact' for nil:NilClass"